# Hadoop: maintain memory cache between iterated map jobs

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, bigdata

I want to iteratively call map-reduce jobs in a cluster. In each iteration the mappers should handle about 10000 bulky records. In each iteration, the master node calls those mappers with a different parameter, but the input records stay same. There’s no need to load those records each time the mapper is called; it would be great to cache them in the main memory across iterations, and just process given a new parameter value.

I plan to use AWS Elastic MapReduce, which runs Hadoop, and my implementation uses Python, so Java API does not seem helpful. Is it possible to implement such caching in that architecture? If not, what are the suitable architectures in AWS or other public clouds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map/Reduce in Hadoop 1 is not suited for this. you should take a look at Hadoop 2.0 and YARN which enables more flexible models.

You can also look at [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/index.html) which [can run on AWS](http://hama.apache.org/hama_on_clouds.html) and support python through [steaming](http://wiki.apache.org/hama/HamaStreaming)

Comment: streaming*.

Hama worked for me, thanks. Hama Streaming is still not mature though.